# Decision boundary for Cross entropy loss and Least square loss

Tags: least-squares, cross-entropy

We can see the source [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04076).
My question is that why cross entropy loss has a boundary line in slope but least square loss has horizontal boundary.
Can somebody explain?
[image]